# Unable to insert single quotes in SQL Server 2016

Tags: node.js, sql-server, loopbackjs, sql-server-2016

I am trying to insert data in my SQL Server and I am using loopback framework in the backend.

But at the time of inserting a string with single quotes, I get an error

> RequestError: Unclosed quotation mark after the character string ',8272)
>   SELECT id AS insertId from @insertedIds

and the string which I am trying to insert is like this

```
An open-ended equity fund investing in stocks which are currently undervalued to their future earning potential and carry medium risk profile to provide 'Capital Appreciation',
```

I tried to resolve this issue by replacing single quotes but afterward, when I am selecting data from the database again this error is happening.

Code is something like this

```
let mutualFundRecord = {

    fundObjective: An open-ended equity fund investing in stocks which are currently undervalued to their future earning potential and carry medium risk profile to provide 'Capital Appreciation'

   }

       function updateRecordData(mutualFundRecord, callback) {
            const promise = new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
              let promiseP1;
              if (!mutualFundRecord.instrument || !mutualFundRecord.instrument.id) {

                promiseP1 = app.models.Instrument.create(mutualFundRecord)
                  .then(function (newlyCreatedInstrument) {
                    mutualFundRecord.mutualFundDetails.instrumentId = newlyCreatedInstrument.id;
                    return app.models.MutualFundDetails.create(mutualFundRecord.mutualFundDetails);
                  });
              }
    }
```

Comment: Please post your code. Looks like you are building a SQL string with the data, which is unsafe and opens your code to SQL injection. You should use parameters for your inserts.

Comment: @Piotr I have added the code please have a look..

Answer (score 0):

If you try to assign the string with a single quote(s) in it to the variable, you would get the same error as you mentioned in your question:

```sql
declare @text nvarchar(100) = 'That's all folks'
```

Error: Unclosed quotation mark after the character string ''.

What you need to do is to replace each single quote character in the string with two single quote characters - that's called "escaping" the character.

Following code is a small demo and it will show you that although in the code you see two quote character, only one quote will be written into the database:

```sql
declare @text nvarchar(100) = 'That''s all folks'

select @text as Txt
into #t

select Txt from #t
```

> That's all folks

Comment: I tried this solution already but even after replacing single quotes with 2 single quotes it gave me the same error.

Comment: So where are you getting an error, when inserting or selecting the data?